# How to export Google Sheets to a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-sheets

I have already found [this blog](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-json-formatted-text/) which links [this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pamelafox/1878143/raw/6c23f71231ce1fa09be2d515f317ffe70e4b19aa/exportjson.js) for the Google Sheets App Script.

But I have some problems with it.

1. When I choose the list style JSON then it will put the sheets value:key pairs into an empty array. For example if the sheet name is data and the sheet has these values..

[image]

.. it will export like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ],
```

To access the key:value pairs I need to use this path:

```
data.0.key1
```

Instead I want to access it like this:

```
data.key1
```

I noticed when using hash style in the config then the script doesn't generate an array.

But here comes issue 2.

2. Either I'm doing something wrong or the script has a bug in hash mode. If the sheet contains these values...

[image]

...then the export will look like this:

```
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "key1": "value2",
        "key2": "value3"
    },
}
```

The id will be included twice. Just a small thing but not too nice.

3. And my third problem is that I didn't find any documentation on how to nest objects with the script. I don't even know if it is possible. But unfortunately I didn't find another script which can do all of this.

I tried finding a different script and I also tried to edit the linked script. But I wasn't successful, lol.

Can you please help me as I'm still a Javascript beginner or do you know another easy way to turn Google Sheets into JSON?

Or alternatively do you know a good JSON editor? Because I don't want to slowly edit hundreds of nested objects manually while bothering with the correct syntax.

Thanks for reading and thank you in advance!

Comment: can you expand on the data source a little? is it a list of key/value pairs (sideways though) or can there be multiple values, so like a table with headers?

Comment: Do you have 1 row in each google sheet? otherwise under `key1` there will be mutiple values.

Comment: @NickSlash It is a Google Sheet table and the headers are the keys and the rows below are the values. I added screenshots.

Comment: @SedatPolat Each sheet has one row which are the keys and then below there are the values. I added screenshots. 
But what I want is nested objects. I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Looking at the result from your example export, your data needs to be transposed. its expecting data on rows not columns.

Comment: @NickSlash Oh maybe my screenshots where misleading. Each row is one JSON document. The first row are the key names.